# how can i create a true, binary excel file using pure asp

Tags: asp-classic

is it possible to create a binary excel file in asp classic?

the common method is using this

```
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"

Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.txt"
```

which is not a "true" excel file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .net you could use the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel namespace - very easy to use, if you have access to .net i'd certainly go for that.

You say "in pure asp" - if this means without com objects etc - i dont think it's possible.

If however you wish to persevere with classic asp with the option of using a com object you can create full binary spreadsheets using the Interop com object - to do this you will need Excel installed on the webserver.

For example, to open a blank excel file on disk (i.e. a template), change a value and save the finished file:

```
'#### Ready Excel
Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
ExcelApp.Application.Visible = True

'#### Open a blank Excel File
Set ExcelBook = ExcelApp.workbooks.Open("d:\wwwroot2\blankTemplate.xls")

'#### Select a sheet and change the value of a cell
ExcelBook.Worksheets("SheetName").Cells(1, 1).Value = "Lorem Ipsum"

'#### Switch between sheets
ExcelBook.Worksheets("AnotherSheetName").Select

'#### Save the finished file with a different name (to leave the template ready for easy re-use)
ExcelBook.SaveAs "d:\wwwroot2\FinishedFile.xls"

'#### Tidy up
ExcelBook.Close
ExcelApp.Application.Quit
Set ExcelApp = Nothing 
Set ExcelBook = Nothing
```

Good thing about this method is the interop com object mimics VBA methods etc very closely, so if your ever unsure how to do something, record a macro in excel, view the raw vba, the code it produces, specifically the methods and parameters would be very similar in most cases to the code you would use for the com object.